# Use the “sql” form field type in extension xml only if the table exists

Tags: plugin, sql, fields

I developed a ***plugin*** for Joomla!, and I have the below sql parameter field in my sampleplugin.xml

```
<field
    name="cb_fields"
    type="sql"
    label="Select CB fields"
    query="SELECT name FROM #__comprofiler_fields WHERE `table`= '#__comprofiler' AND `published`='1' AND `type`='text'"
    key_field="name"
    value_field="name"
    multiple="multiple" />
```

I got sql error because the CB is not installed on a client's website. The problem is how to check if the table #__comprofiler_fields exists first before getting data from there ?

Thank you.

Comment: because you have abandoned this page, the system keeps bumping it to the top of the question queue.  Please come back to us and progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom form field type. From SQL form field type documentation:

> Warning!
>
> Using this generic form field type forces you to write SQL in an XML
>   file and is rather limited. For more flexibility, consider creating
>   your own, specific form field type by subclassing the JFormField
>   class.

https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Comment: How to define a custom form field type inside the plugin xml file ?

Comment: From _Creating a custom form field type_ documentation: 

**Using the custom field type** >
To use the field type City, we need to update the XML file that contains the form fields. Open your XML file located in **administrator/components/com_phonebook/models/forms** and add the field in the usual way...

@sharky